# Standalone GUI client for TFS 2010 Source Control

Tags: tfs

I'm looking for a TFS 2010 GUI client that I can use outside of an IDE. I'm only looking to use the source control features in this case. I'm not talking about work items or build management.

Ideally it would be a complete client that can be used on a machine where Visual Studio is not installed.

Options I know about and why I'm not satisfied with them:

- [TFS Power Tools - Windows Shell Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3e8c9b68-6e39-4577-b9b7-78489b5cb1da)

  - Must have a working copy to use... see [chicken or the egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg)
  - Missing features: view history, branch / merge, revert
- [SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/)

  - TFS 2010 not yet supported

Are there others that I don't know about?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't install visual studio just for TFS?

Comment: @Ryan - I have projects that don't involve visual studio (java, ruby projects) but I still want to keep them under version control.

Comment: I would really love this. We do dev in multiple IDEs and it's a bitch having to keep VS2008 open and memory hungry just for Source Control when I'm in and out of other IDES all day long.

Sounds like a candidate for an open source project to me.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can install Team Explorer (on the TFS install DVD, or you can download it [from MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=fe4f9904-0480-4c9d-a264-02fedd78ab38)) without needing to have VS2010 installed - Team Explorer will install a 'shell' VS2010 with only the TFS features available - none of the IDE components.

Update: the [VS11 beta](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28976) version is now available.

Comment: Thanks, Ben. I have not been able to find TFS explorer for 2010. It was not included on the DVD and I'm not able to find it for download anywhere. From what I've read it is only included if you have the "Ultimate" edition or some such thing.

Comment: Here you go: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=fe4f9904-0480-4c9d-a264-02fedd78ab38

Comment: Do people connecting from Team Explorer require a TFS license? do you know how that works?, right now we are using the web access, but would prefer to use Team Explorer if there is no license restriction...

Comment: Team Explorer and the TFS Web Access tool require a full license. See http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13350 for the details

Comment: Just as an addition (2 years on!), TFS11 Explorer is here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28976, and of course an explicit license isn't required as such due to there being an Express edition.

Comment: How nice. 300 mega for a version control. Nice logic MS.

Comment: Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, Download is marked as FREE - whatever this means, here is the link:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40776

Answer (score 6):

If you use eclipse I've heard good things about the teamprise stuff but haven't tried it myself. They got bought by microsoft and now you can download the eclipse plugin [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=af1f5168-c0f7-47c6-be7a-2a83a6c02e57&displaylang=en) It also looks like it has a fully functional command line client that you could use instead of TFS Power Tools.

From the description: "Eclipse plug-in and cross-platform command-line client for Visual Studio 2010 Team Foundation Server"

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This isn't quite what I'm looking for though as Eclipse is another IDE and I'm looking for something more lightweight. The command line tool isn't technically a GUI client.

Comment: You can download the Eclipse Platform Runtime if you wanted (http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6RC2-201005201744/index.php#PlatformRuntime) - 49Mb. These drops contain only the Eclipse Platform with user documentation and no source and no programmer documentation. The Java development tools and Plug-in Development Environment are NOT included.  You can then install Team Explorer Everywhere into it

Comment: huh? how exactly is a bare bones build of Eclipse anything BUT lightweight? without plugins its basically Notepad++

Answer (score 4):

If you have a SVN client, such as TortoiseSVN  on your machine, you can use SVNBridge.

SvnBridge acts as a bridge between a subversion client and TFS. You point SvnBridge at the TFS server, and point the subversion client at SvnBridge. This allows the developer to use a subversion client with any TFS server without needing to change the TFS server in any way. See http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

`.\English\VSTFS2010\TeamExplorer` it is here on the TFS install.

Answer (score 0):

The iso for team explorer is here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=329

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST use TFS 2010, you may get away with Visual Studio Code, plus an TFS Extension.  However, these extensions require TF.exe; you will still need VS installed but at least the program you would open (VS Code) has a much lesser memory footprint.

Comment: I recommend you migrate to git as soon as possible.